# Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This code:

```
import * as React from 'react';                                                                                              
                                                                                 
const Component = () => <div/>;                                                  
                
function culprit<P>(node: React.ReactElement<P>) {
  console.log(node);
}
                                                             
culprit(<Component/>);
```

...produces this compilation error when compiling with TypeScript:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'ReactElement'.   Type 'null' is not assignable
> to type 'ReactElement

This only happens when the **strictNullChecks** TypeScript compilation flag is set to `true`.

Yes I could disable that flag, but I want it on for added compile-time checking/safety.

If I change the last line to this:

```
culprit( (<Component/> as React.ReactElement<any>) );
```

...it works with the flag set to `true`.

I've recently tried migrating from "plain" JavaScript to TypeScript in a React project and this is tripping up all my tests, so adding all the TypeScript type assertions to all these occurrences in the test code will be a pain.

Is this a bug, or do I have no other choice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is apparently an issue which was introduced in the 15.0.5 React type definitions. If you change to 15.0.4, everything should be fine.

See this issue: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/14284

Comment: I have tried `@types/react` versions 15.0.6, 15.0.4, 15.0.0 and all of them still produce the problem for me, unfortunately.

Comment: Version 0.14.57 works, but that was before the union type with `| null` was introduced (which is what you seem to have been trying to get me on). Yet React is supposed to allow render functions to return null, so I don't think the React type definition is wrong, I think all type definitions which have not allowed for `null` need to get updated. I got this `culprit` function signature from Enzyme.js, so its type definitions will need updating.

Comment: 15.0.4 fixed my problem, but I guess you must be doing something different (or have something different in your setup).

Answer (score 52):

If you have JSX inside your component or component test file must have `.tsx`
as your file extension. My code was not compiling as I had the .ts file extension. The moment I renamed it to `.tsx`/`jsx` it started working nicely!

Please also note that I was using Typescript, so that's why I renamed it to `.tsx`. In case you are using ES6 rename it to `.jsx`.

Comment: oh god, I was literally blind to that, so simple. Thank you, king.

Answer (score 4):

This happens when I don't return JSX inside of React Fragment or empty tags.

```
const ErrorMessage: FC<ErrorProps> = (props) => {
    if (!isEmpty(props.errors)) {

        return Object.entries(props.errors).map((item) => (
            <Typography component="span">{item[0]}</Typography>
        ))
    };

    return <></>;
};
```

When I added empty tags everything worked as expected.

```
const ErrorMessage: FC<ErrorProps> = (props) => {
    if (!isEmpty(props.errors)) {

        return (
            <>
                {Object.entries(props.errors).map((item) => (
                    <Typography component="span">{item[0]}</Typography>
                ))}
            </>
        )
    };

    return <></>;
};
```

Also, if we remove the `return <></>` statement error will be shown. Component, as I wrote, always need to return correct JSX component.

Versions

- React: 17.0.2
- @types/react: 17.0.34
- TypeScript: 4.6.4

Answer (score 4):

In my specific case it was looking for `JSX.Element` instead of just `Element`.  Not sure what the correct fix for that is, but updating my type definition to `Element | JSX.Element` resolved the issue.