# how to create a wrapper that changes the props for the component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I m trying to do something with react components for the first time and need your help,
I want to wrap a component inside another one dynamically and changing its props.
for example, let's say I have this component:

let's suppose I want to pass the `key3` from a wrapper

Note: using React-Native with TypeScript

```
type Props { key1: string, key2: string, key3: any }
const FirstComponent = ({ key1, key2, key3 }:Props) => {
   return <View>
    <Text>{key1} and {key2} with {key3}</Text>
<View/>
}
```

wrapper example

```
const FirstComponentWrapper = (props:Props) => {
 const value = 'something';
  return <FirstComponent {...props} key3={value} />
}
```

the wrapper here lets the component have the access to the `key3` value.
if I have a large app with a lot of components and I can't create it each time, so I m looking for a way to create the wrapper somewhere so I can call it easily.

example :

```
type Props = {
  component: React.ReactNode // not just function component it can be also class 
                             // component ;
  newValue: any;
}
export const Wrapper = ({ component, newValue }:Props) => {
  // this is what I missed
  // looking to return any passed component here as in the example I mentioned with new 
  // value that's added to the prop
}
```

any help? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`children`](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/react/react-pass-props-to-children/#passing-props-to-children-in-react-using-react-cloneelement) in `Props` to render your wrapped components with your `Wrapper` component

```
type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode 
  newValue: any;
}
export const Wrapper = ({ children, newValue, ...otherProps }: Props) => {
  return React.cloneElement(children, {...otherProps, key3: newValue})
}
```

Usage

```
<Wrapper newValue="value3">
  <FirstComponent key1="value1" key2="value2" />
</Wrapper>
```

---

Another way, you can have a [higher-order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) (HOC) to modify your props before your wrapped components get rendered

```
const withModifiedProps = (WrappedComponent: React.ReactNode) => {
   const Wrapper = ({ newValue, ...props }) => {
      return <WrappedComponent {...props} key3={newValue} />
   }
   return Wrapper
}
```

After that, you can wrap your component with HOC

```
export default withModifiedProps(FirstComponent)
```

Whenever you render `FirstComponent`, you can pass `newValue` to it that will automatically populate `key3` as the replacement for `newValue`

```
<FirstComponent key1="value1" key2="value2" newValue="value3" />
```

Comment: thanks, when I pass a class component on the first example I got this error  ` Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'JSXElementConstructor<never>'.  `

Comment: Could you try to modify `children` to `children as React.ReactElement<any>`. You also can check [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036992/argument-of-type-element-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-reactelement) for the type check problem as a reference @AzizMobarak

Comment: on my case I have passed the class component to the `Wrap` function so it will work as a children but the return function is a `React Element` , and when doing `WithWrap(ClassComponent)` it says it shoud return `JSXElementConstructor<never>`  that is not compatible with the` React Element`, and I use just the newValue.

Comment: it means something like this `<Wrapper newValue="value3">
  {children}
</Wrapper>`

Comment: But everything is working fine for you? Do you struggle with any variable types? @AzizMobarak

Comment: no it says `Type Element is not assignable to type JSXElementConstructor<never>`

Comment: and other explaination to got what I mean exactly , this is a part of code

Comment: `const WithNavigation = (children: React.JSXElementConstructor<never>): React.ReactElement => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const route = useRoute();
  return (
    <Wrapper navigation={navigation} route={route}>
      {children}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}; `

Comment: the children here can be used on that case like this it shows me the error I mentioned

Comment: It's a prop, so you should introduce them in a pair of brackets like `({ children })` @AzizMobarak